# dynamically specify select columns linq

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, func

Using linq, I'm trying to implement the following logic-

```
Iqueryable.Select(q=> new {
    if a then q.field1,q.field2,q.field3
    else if b then q.field1, q.field4
    else q.field5,q.field6,q.field7,q.field8
});
```

Any ideas for the best way to do this?

Comment: You want to dynamically change the return type of the expression? [This may be the essence of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555103/424129), but it'll be a hell of a verbose linq expression by the time you're done.

Comment: You can only do this by returning a dynamic. anonymous types are type-safe. What you are doing is not. I may have some code for you, but it is at work. I dynamically create an anonymous type based on string input. But it is all at work, I have a vacation :)

Comment: @S.Akbari that doesn't work

Comment: @Michael sounds nice, would love to see

Comment: Found something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select). Maybe you somehow can use that. Otherwise, I will try to get back to you when back to work in about two weeks.

Comment: so far nothing working for me besides just building my query with a long if else.... don't really like it too much. any more professional ideas are welcome

Comment: If `q` really is the same `q` in every case, have you confirmed that there's no performance hit from returning a class that has all the fields, but simply not initializing the fields you don't care about in any particular case? Why not have a method `Func<Q,R> GetF(a,b,...)` which returns the right `Select` lambda according to your conditions `a`/`b` etc. Then `query.Select(GetF(a,b,c))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly encapsulate this into a method that returns `dynamic`, although you lose your type safety and always with dynamic, a bit of performance.

```
public dynamic DynamicSelect(Expression<Func<Address, dynamic>> query)
{
    return Addresses.Select(query).Take(1).ToList();
}
```

You can then call it and retrieve data from it like so:

```
var result = DynamicSelect(q => new {q.Id, q.AddressLine1});
Console.WriteLine(result[0].Id);
```

When using `DbSets`, you can even take this a step further and genericize it:

```
public dynamic DynamicSelect<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> query)
{
    return context.DbSet<TEntity>.Select(query).Take(1).ToList();
}
```

Personally I'd ask yourself if this type of flexibility is really necessary.  You're killing your type safety for a marginal increase in "flexibility".

Comment: thx, I can't lose any performance, but I do need to keep changing my list of fields. I don't want a long if statement bec I can have lots of conditions - like if a then if nestedCondtion&&secondNestedCondition then.... else if nestedCondition then.... else if b...

Comment: @MikeTurner you'd have to measure the impact to ***verify*** if there is a ***demonstrable*** performance hit.  I can't assure you that there is or is not.  It depends on your situation.  But as always with dynamic, it needs to be called out.

Comment: not even sure how this thing would work for me. what I would really love is just something like - 
if condition -- add fieldOne to select, if conditionTwo - add fieldTwo to select, if conditionThree --- add fieldThree to select etc.

Comment: like would work great if I can pass a list of propertyInfo into my .Select(q=> listPropInfo)

Comment: @MikeTurner you can't change the signature of `Select()`...it is what it is.  All you can do is work within the context of the method. It requires an expression that takes in a type and returns a new type.  So you'd have to work around that.  If you can stop needing to use an anonymous type and instead use a concrete type with all the potential fields, this becomes a much easier problem.

Comment: nope. wont work. I guess I can just use system.linq.dynamic and pass a string of my concatenated fields

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this

```
        IQueryable query;  
        if (a)
            query.Select(q=> new {q.field1,q.field2,q.field3});
        else if (b)
            query.Select(q=> new {q.field1, q.field4});
        else
            .Select(q=> new {q.field5,q.field6,q.field7,q.field8});
```

Comment: was looking for something more dynamic looking... like an anonymous func or something cooler